# Formula to Find the First Weekday of a Given Month

Tags: formula, formula-field, date

I am currently trying to create a formula field that will display the first weekday of a month. So for instance 7/1/2016 was a Friday so the field would have displayed that date. But, if it would have been a Saturday then it should add two days to display the following Monday. Below is what I currently have, but it is returning `#Error!` in the field for my test record and it should be showing 7/1/2016.

```
DATE(YEAR(Month_Start_Date_Copy__c), MONTH(Month_Start_Date_Copy__c),
CASE(MOD(DATE(YEAR(Month_Start_Date_Copy__c),MONTH(Month_Start_Date_Copy__c),1) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7), 
0, 2, 
1, 1, 
0))
```

What I am trying to do here is have it return the day of the week, 0 being Saturday and then add 2 days to get to Monday and then if it is Sunday add 1 day to get to Monday. Anything else should just display the date that is in `Month_Start_Date_Copy__c`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `CASE(..., 6, 3, 0, 2, 1)`? You can't use a day value of 0, you definitely need to adjust up by 1.

Comment: I'm not following. Can you explain more what you are asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you should have:

- If the 1st is Saturday, the first weekday is on `DATE(<year>, <month>, 3)`
- If the 1st is Sunday, the first weekday is on `DATE(<year>, <month>, 2)`
- Otherwise the 1st *is* a weekday, so just use `DATE(<year>, <month>, 1)`

If your `MOD` outputs `0` for `Sunday`, it should yield `6` for `Saturday`. Hence this alternative seems like it should work:

```
DATE(YEAR(...), MONTH(...), CASE(
    MOD(...),
    6, 3,
    0, 2,
    1
))
```

No valid date will ever have a day of 0, so your fallback value for the `CASE` statement is expected to yield an error.

Comment: Oh alright. I get what you are saying now. I just tried it and it seems to be working properly. Going to test a little bit more though.